# Disabled domain remains active. Varnish:80, Nginx:8080

Tags: nginx, varnish

I need to move dev.mydomain.com to mydomain.com to make new site available on the official domain.

In order to do this I:

1. created new vhost record in /etc/nginx/sites-available for domain.com
2. created symlink in sites-enabled for #1
3. reloaded nginx

At this point the site is available for either dev.mydomain.com and mydomain.com. Now I need to disable dev.mydomain.com:

4. removed symlink form sites-enabled for dev.mydomain.com
5. reloaded nginx

As it doesn't have any effect I also tried:

7. remove vhost record for dev.mydomain.com form sites-available
8. reload whole server
9. comment out any mention of dev.mydomain.com in varnish default.vcl
10. purge Varnish cache

System: Ubuntu 14.04, Varnish on 80 port, Nginx on 8080

UPD: the vhost is configured to use HTTPS only.

UPD2: Nginx vhost config:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/mydomain.com.key;
        root /home/mydomain.com/web;
[...]
}

server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        root /home/hobancards/web;
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nginx serve any subdomain automatically. 
To disable this edit vhost file as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/347069/how-do-i-refuse-a-request-to-a-subdomain-in-nginx?answertab=votes#tab-top).